# Enable / disable DOMMouseScroll mousewheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent, mouselistener

I´m trying to get the same scrolling transitions like on http://www.hugeinc.com between the last project section and the #main (last) element.

Here´s what I have done so far: 
http://codepen.io/lorenzwoehr/pen/bpYzYB

This function scrolls to the next section:

```
$("body").addClass("shifted", setTimeout(function() { 
    $("body").css({"overflow":"auto"});
}, 600));
```

**The Problem**

This prevents "normal" scrolling on the #main element:

```
$(window).on({
    'DOMMouseScroll mousewheel': elementScroll
});
```

How can I enable scrolling when the #main element is "shifted"?

Answer (score 0):

You're returning `false` in your function `elementScroll` in line 40.
Therefore it will not scroll. You need to return true in order to scroll.

As a solution to this you maybe want to check which element is targeted in your scroll event. For example like this:
`return e.target.id != 'project-2';`
Then it will only propagate the scroll event when your target element is not the element with the id: `project-2` which is your slide.

See the edited [codepen](http://codepen.io/InsOp/pen/dMZLzd)